Export and plot using a Python notebook a 2D contour plot from Topspin
From the Topspin program, I am trying export a selected region in

an adequate format

to afterwards

be plotted using a Python code.

To start with I do not know which format to be exported is the right one and then, the code plot it being able to modify the axis afterwards too (by using plt.set_x(y)lim(). This last thing mentioned would be useful to set sub-regions of the previously selected region.
I have tried the following:
Right Click on the selected region > Save Display Region To ...

If I choose the last option, a large .txt file with the values in the z axis of the XY grid appear but information about the x and y axis is lost and one cannot select a sub-region afterwords.
Any suggestion for choosing the right format and a code ?

In case someone is facing the same problem and cannot find any answer, here there is the solution:
https://github.com/jjhelmus/nmrglue/issues/214
Here the code:
# read data
dic, data = ng.bruker.read_pdata("datafolder/1/pdata/1")

# read in axis ppm parameters
udic = ng.bruker.guess_udic(dic, data, strip_fake=True)
uc = {i: ng.fileiobase.uc_from_udic(udic, dim=i) for i in (0, 1)}
axis_limits = [*uc[1].ppm_limits(), *uc[0].ppm_limits()]

# contour levels
levels = [data.max() / 20 * 1.4**i for i in range(10)]  # change as needed

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contour(
    data.real, 
    levels=levels, 
    extent=axis_limits, 
    cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, # change as per your preference 
    linewidths=0.5, # change as per your preference
)

ax.set_xlim(11.5, 6)  # change as needed
ax.set_ylim(135, 105)  # change as needed

plt.show()

